# HP DV1000 Laptop won't start. Flashing "power" light

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting

I've been handed a laptop to "clean-up", it appears to be infested with spyware and various limewire type downloads.

It had a habit of randomly shutting down after 30 seconds, BSODs if cables connected and so forth.

I've booted into safe mode, installed CCleaner, did a quick cleanup of the registry and removed a load of temporary files. Next I installed Avast antivirus and hey presto it found a substantial amount of trojans and other such nasties.

Rebooted, then once again it switched off, only this time I can't get it to switch back on. When I press the power button the blue "lightning bolt" LED flashes, but nothing happens.

I have a similar laptop at home, the dv6000 and I've had the same problems. I bought a new power lead which let me boot it up but then it stopped again.

Is there anything I can do? Or was it pretty much the last nail in the coffin? Seems quite common for this model to short out on the motherboard

Comment: just to state the obvious, the battery was on 98% before reboot so its not flat. All of this happens whilst running on battery power, just plugged into mains but no change

Comment: Let it cool down and then try to power it back on. Does it turn on after a break?

Comment: I've left it to cooldown for a couple of hours, no change.. :S

Comment: try to take out one ram chip and see if it boot's up.like marcin was thinking, it might be overheating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some digging on HPs website I found a table explaning what different series of flashes denote a problem with. Here is the page; http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=uk&lang=en&product=435618&docname=c01732674

As you will see, the bottom one explains that a continuous blinking Power LED means there is insufficient power.

Not sure why the laptop would be getting insufficient power if it is plugged in to the mains. Unless there is a problem with the power adapter or you are using the incorrect adapter which is not supplying enough juice to the laptop, as explained [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=uk&lang=en&product=435618&docname=c01727443).

As doesnt seem to be a problem with the laptop its self, I would reccomend getting another power adapter designed for this laptop.

Hope this sorts out your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the battery and then putting it back in.  That got rid of the flashing and started charging the battery again.